# positioning div elements using css

Tags: css, xhtml

I always seem to have problems with CSS layouts. What is the best to position 'div' elements on the page. For example i have created the following:

See my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JJw7c/3/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            this is the header
            <div class="menu">
                menu goes here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            main content goes here
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        footer
    </div>
</body>
</html>

body
{
    margin:10px;
}
.container
{
    border:1px solid black;
    min-height:400px;
    width:100%;
}

.header
{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100px;
}

.menu
{
    border:1px solid green;
    height:20px;
    width:50%;
    float:right;
}

.main
{
    border:1px solid grey;
    min-height:100px;
    margin:20px;
}

.footer
{
    border:1px solid green;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

Lets say i want to position an icon within the lower right of the header but i want to be specific.

Do i use position relative then top:20px etc etc.. or position:absolute? or do i use margin-right:200px? or could i use floats and then position absolute? <<< Please can you explain when I would use these and if possible update my jsfiddle with each example.

Thanks

Comment: maybe learn something about css positioning first ;-) http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/ . If you want to position an icon, you should use `position: absolute`, provided that surrounding container have `position: relative`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
right:0px;
```

to the icon class and add `position:relative;` to .header

Comment: Why do we add position relative to the header?

Comment: because coordinates of an absolute positioned element are always referred to the first non-static parent (so the icon is anchored to the header)

Answer (score 2):

you could use position `absolute + relative`
assign `position: relative` to the `.header` element, then add your icon within using `position: absolute`: `top` and `left` property applied to the icon will be referred respect to the `header` element (because it's the first non-static element parent of the icon)

The main advantage of this technique is that the presence of the icon won't affect at all the position of other elements inside header (since is absolute positioned)

Comment: anyone could explain the downvote? it's the same answer (posted later) with 2 upvotes...

Comment: I up-voted you to get rid of the minus. Some people probably didnt understand what you said.